# Usage of Eloquent objects as dictionary tables in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have different classes that act as "dictionary" lists, for example, for `CarType` class I hava table with `id`, `value` fields (1, 'small'; 2, 'big' ..)

Is there a way I can use such model as a map list (with cached data in memory) to have sometthing like that in my blade files:

`{{ CartType->value($model->type_id) }}`.

The idea would be

- to load in memory all the data (or at leas after 2 requests of
  different values)
- to be easily to wrap around some fields of the model

Comment: I find your question quite confusing (either wording or your example), but I think you're looking for Eloquent's Relationships. On each model class, you would have a function (for example) `public function getType(){...}` which would contain the relation to another model (again, example) `return $this->hasMany("Type");` Check the documentation http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships for more info.

Comment: I know the concept of the relationship, but it looks too me a little overhead to do that, when this tables would more static (will change very rarely).

Answer (score 3):

You *can* do this with Eloquent (using relationships, as @TimLewis suggests), but it if's a simple map with just a few values (ie. not hundreds of different options), you'll probably find that Eloquent adds a lot of overhead for such a simple function.

Instead, I'd use database queries inside custom accessors. For example,

Imagine you have a `Car` Eloquent model and each car has exactly one "car type" value (denoted by a `car_type` field in the database).

Imagine that you also have a table in your database for listing car types, called (not surprisingly) `car_types`.

Here's a quick diagram:

```
|------------------|
|cars              |                      |------------------|
|------------------|                      |car_types         |
|id INT PRIMARY_KEY|                      |------------------|
|car_type_id INT   |   -- one-to-many --> |id INT PRIMARY_KEY|
|...               |                      |name CHAR         |
|------------------|                      |------------------|
```

You *could* set up an Eloquent model for `car_type` and define a relationship. That would work just fine, but do you really need all the functionality of an Eloquent model for this?

Instead, you could set up [an accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) on the cars model:

```
class Car extends Eloquent {

    public function getCarTypeAttribute()
    {
        return DB::table('car_types')
            ->select('name')
            ->where('id', '=', $this->car_type_id);
    }
}
```

This will perform better than a full Eloquent model plus relationships.

But you also asked about caching the list. You could easily expand the example above to store the full list in the cache instead of querying each time:

```
class Car extends Eloquent {

    public function getCarTypeAttribute()
    {
        $list = Cache::get('car_types_list');

        if (!$list) {
            $list = DB::table('car_types')->select('name');

            // save in the cache for 60 minutes
            Cache::put('car_types_list', $list, 60);
        }

        // search the list for the type ID
        foreach ($list as $type) {
            if ($type->id===$this->id) {
                return $type;
            }
        }

        // the type wasn't found
        throw new Exception("That's not right!");
    }
}
```

Now, if you have a Car model, you can get the type like this:

```
$car = Car::find(1234);
$type = $car->CarType;
```

Comment: Very good solution! I'm researching a good solution, but the most developers that wrote aboute are using enum or a lot of overhead. 
That solution have a little overhead but after the cache was ready, we got a great performance.